# When designing a website for mobile should I still use the mobile's interface button graphics

Tags: mobile, mobile-web

I am designing a site that will, at the moment, only have a mobile version. I was wondering if I should use the ux buttons and styles from a particular phone or just design with mobile design requirements in mind. If you have any good pointers for mobile design guidelines, please do include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously think that you should focus on making it unique. You want it to support the variety of screen sizes and resolutions together with the different OS the devices run. Also portrait vs landscape mode. I like to be able to differ native mobile apps from web pages and web apps.

There are also a few other things to think of like minimize http requests and load. Minify production CSS and JS. Optimize images, actually use as little images as possible.

There are loads of resources and I use to read a lot of articles at http://www.smashingmagazine.com

You could also look up the book: [Mobile First by Luke Wroblewski](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1937557022)

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile website should differentiate itself from a native mobile app by using it's own style buttons (and other assets), to avoid landing in the uncanny valley.  A web app is never going to be quite as seamless as a native app, if you get too close to being native users are going to start noticing all the little things that make it not native.  You want to give the impression that the app is perfect, and an almost native experience is clearly imperfect.